# Unable to get environment variables inside django settings?

Tags: python, django, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I defined my environment variables inside `env/bin/activate` and the following came out from the output when i activated them

```
debug="True"
secret="RI4MgORxGb4c6zhotTHSNXc54lz1IWGbIoETfmj2VB99sPNlk9YMcg4b6qyX"
```

using `echo` in `zsh`. Now that tells me that the environment variables are set properly. I am getting the same inside django settings using

```
DEBUG = True if os.environ.get("debug") == "True" else False
```

The problem comes when i run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

which is unable to find those variables as opposed to

```
 env debug='True' python manage.py run server
```

which works fine in debug mode and production depending on environment variables. What am i missing over here ? is this something because of using `zsh` shell or am i getting the variables wrong way somehow ?

Comment: Did you remember to export those variables to the environment?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams now i feel really silly for missing out on export . Answer and i can accept that. Been thinking for long where i was going wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many shells, setting a variable only does so for the shell process itself. If you want to turn a shell variable into an environment variable then you need to export the variable, usually with the `export` command.